# Proving $\sum_{k=1}^{n}{(-1)^{k+1} {{n}\choose{k}}\frac{1}{k}=H_n}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, inclusion-exclusion, harmonic-numbers, coupon-collector

I've been trying to prove

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{(-1)^{k+1} {{n}\choose{k}}\frac{1}{k}=H_n}$$

I've tried perturbation and inversion but still nothing. I've even tried expanding the sum to try and find some pattern that could relate this to the harmonic series but this just seems surreal. I can't find any logical reasoning behind this identity. I don't understand [Wikipedia's proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation). Is there any proof that doesn't require the integral transform?

Comment: There is a missing term?

Comment: @DiegoMath Thanks, fixed it. Its very late and I'm very tired and very frustrated for not being able to solve this..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem), the expected value of the number $N$ of coupons required for a full collection of $m$ coupon types can be determined in two different ways. In the standard treatment, the expected numbers of coupons to get each new type are added up, yielding the result $mH_m$. But we can also determine this expectation more mundanely from the distribution:

\begin{align}
\def\stir#1#2{\left\{{#1\atop #2}\right\}}
E[N]={}&\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(N\gt n)\\
={}&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(1-\frac{m!}{m^n}\stir nm\right)\\
={}&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(1-\frac{m!}{m^n}\frac1{m!}\sum_{j=0}^m(-1)^{m-j}\binom mjj^n\right)\\
={}&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{m^n}\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}(-1)^{m-j+1}\binom mjj^n\\
={}&\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}(-1)^{m-j+1}\binom mj\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{j^n}{m^n}\\
={}&\sum_{j=1}^m(-1)^{j+1}\binom mj\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(m-j)^n}{m^n}\\
={}&\sum_{j=1}^m(-1)^{j+1}\binom mj\frac mj\\
={}&m\sum_{j=1}^m(-1)^{j+1}\binom mj\frac1j\;.
\end{align}

(Here $\stir nm$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).) Equating the two results yields our identity.

Perhaps the derivation appears slightly less opaque if we avoid the detour through the Stirling numbers and directly apply [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). There are $\binom mj$ ways to select $j$ coupon types that haven't been collected yet, and the probability that $j$ particular coupon types haven't been collected after $n$ draws is $\left(1-\frac jm\right)^n$. Thus

\begin{align}
E[N]={}&\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(N\gt n)\\
={}&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^m(-1)^{j+1}\binom mj\left(1-\frac jm\right)^n\\
={}&\sum_{j=1}^m(-1)^{j+1}\binom mj\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(1-\frac jm\right)^n\\
={}&\sum_{j=1}^m(-1)^{j+1}\binom mj\frac mj\\
={}&m\sum_{j=1}^m(-1)^{j+1}\binom mj\frac1j\;.
\end{align}

We can generalise this to obtain an expression for $H_m-H_k$. The standard treatment shows that the expected value of the number $N_k$ of coupons required until only $k$ coupon types are missing is $m(H_m-H_k)$. Applying inclusion-exclusion in the form of corollary $(7)$ in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/362516), this expected value can also be calculated as

\begin{align}
E[N_k]
&=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(N_k\gt n)
\\
&=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^m(-1)^{j+k+1}\binom{j-1}{k}\binom mj\left(1-\frac jm\right)^n
\\
&=
\sum_{j=1}^m(-1)^{j+k+1}\binom{j-1}{k}\binom mj\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(1-\frac jm\right)^n
\\
&=
\sum_{j=1}^m(-1)^{j+k+1}\binom{j-1}{k}\binom mj\frac mj
\\
&=
m\sum_{j=1}^m(-1)^{j+k+1}\binom{j-1}{k}\binom mj\frac1j\;,
\end{align}

yielding

$$
H_m-H_k=\sum_{j=1}^m(-1)^{j+k+1}\binom{j-1}{k}\binom mj\frac1j\;.
$$

Comment: Excellent answer! Took me some time ( and external reading ) to completely understand what you wrote.

Comment: I really like your answer. I was wondering if this was related to the average number of cycles in a random permutation. Do you think if there is some relevance between them? I thought about this because the average number of cycles in a random permutation in $S_n$ is also $H_n$.

Comment: @i707107: That's an interesting idea. I thought about it a bit but haven't been able to come with a connection. Meanwhile, here's a nice proof of that result: If we count the cycles by their least elements, the expected number of cycles is the sum of the probabilities of the elements to be the least in their cycle, which is $\frac1k$ for the $k$-th element (the probability of starting a cycle with that element and then at some point choosing it as the first of the first $k$ elements to continue the cycle).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I thought about the connection to the cycles, but I could not find any, other than having $H_n$ as expected value. Maybe the best combinatorial setting to this identity is coupon collector problem.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a rather elementary solution:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k-1} \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{k}
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{j=k}^{n} (-1)^{k-1} \binom{j-1}{k-1} \frac{1}{k} \tag{1} \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{j} (-1)^{k-1} \binom{j}{k} \frac{1}{j} \tag{2} \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{1}{j}. \tag{3}
\end{align*}

- In $\text{(1)}$, we utilized the identity $ \binom{n}{k} = \sum_{j=k}^{n} \binom{j-1}{k-1} $ for $1 \leq k \leq n$. This follows from the usual 'hockey stick argument'.
- In $\text{(2)}$, we changed the order of summation and applied the identity $\binom{j-1}{k-1}\frac{1}{k} = \frac{(j-1)!}{(j-k)!k!} = \binom{j}{k}\frac{1}{j}$ for $1 \leq k \leq j$.
- In $\text{(3)}$, the identity $ \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} = 0 $ ($n \geq 1$) is used to simplify the inner sum. Notice that this is a direct consequence of the binomial theorem.

---

*Addendum.* I realized that my solution can be considered as a shorthand version of **@leonbloy**'s inductive proof (though I came up with this independently).

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[2]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}\left(\,{#2}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> The Sangchul Lee comment is related to the $\ul{first\ answer}$. Indeed, I decided to add another one.

1. \begin{align}
   &\color{#f00}{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k + 1}{n \choose k}\,{1 \over k}} =
   \sum_{k = 1}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k + 1}{n \choose k}\int_{0}^{1}x^{k - 1}\,\dd x =
   -\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{n \choose k}\pars{-x}^{k}\,{\dd x \over x}
   \\[3mm] = &\
   -\int_{0}^{1}{\pars{1 - x}^{n} - 1\over x}\,\dd x\ \stackrel{x\ \to\ 1 - x}{=}\
   \int_{0}^{1}{x^{n} - 1\over x - 1}\,\dd x =
   \int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}x^{k - 1}\,\dd x =
   \sum_{k = 1}^{n}\int_{0}^{1}x^{k - 1}\,\dd x\
   \\[3mm] = &\
   \sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over k}\ \stackrel{\mathrm{def.}}{=}
   \color{#f00}{H_{n}}
   \end{align}

   ---
2. \begin{align}
   &\color{#f00}{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k + 1}{n \choose k}\,{1 \over k}} =
   \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{k + 1}\,{1 \over k}{n \choose n - k} =
   \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{k + 1}\,{1 \over k}\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}
   {\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{n - k + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
   \\[3mm] = &
   \oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}
   {\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{n + 1}}\ \overbrace{%
   \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{k + 1}\,{z^{k} \over k}}
   ^{\ds{=\ \ln\pars{1 + z}}}\
   \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} =
   \oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}
   {\pars{1 + z}^{n}\ln\pars{1 + z} \over z^{n + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
   \\[3mm] = &\
   \lim_{x \to 0}\partiald{}{x}\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}
   {\pars{1 + z}^{n + x} \over z^{n + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} =
   \lim_{x \to 0}\partiald{}{x}{x + n \choose n} =
   {1 \over n!}\lim_{x \to 0}\partiald{}{x}
   \bracks{\Gamma\pars{x + n + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{x + 1}}
   \\[3mm] = &\
   {1 \over n!}
   \bracks{{\Gamma\pars{n + 1}\Psi\pars{n + 1}\Gamma\pars{1} - \Gamma\pars{1}\Psi\pars{1}\Gamma\pars{n + 1} \over \Gamma^{2}\pars{1}}} =
   \Psi\pars{n + 1} - \Psi\pars{1}
   \\[3mm] = &\
   n\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{k + n + 1}\pars{k + 1}} =
   \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over k} - {1 \over k + n}} =
   \sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over k}\ \stackrel{\mathrm{def.}}{=}\
   \color{#f00}{H_{n}}
   \end{align}

Comment: This is the very proof (in reverse order) linked in OP's question, where OP explicitly said: "*... I don't understand [Wikipedia's proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation).*"

Comment: @SangchulLee I'm sorry I didn't check the Wikipedia link before I wrote my answer. I was surprised nobody did anything like this one or/and close to it: It means everybody check the Wikipedia link but me. I'll delete it tomorrow ( such that this comment is visible for awhile ) or/and I'll write a different one. Thanks for your remark.

Comment: I actually like this argument. I am not sure what makes OP hard to understand it, but I guess you may improve your answer so as to make it comprehensible to OP.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we seek to verify that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^{k+1} \frac{1}{k} = H_n.$$

Now observe that

$$\frac{1}{k} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{k+1}} \log\frac{1}{1-z} \; dz$$

where we take $\epsilon < 1$ so that the logarithmic term is analytic.

We get for the sum

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z} \log\frac{1}{1-z} 
\sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^{k+1} \frac{1}{z^k}
\; dz$$

The term for $k=0$ yields

$$-\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z} \log\frac{1}{1-z} = 0$$

and we may lower $k$ to zero, getting for the sum

$$-\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z} \log\frac{1}{1-z} 
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^{k} \frac{1}{z^k}
\; dz
\\ = -\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z} 
\left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right)^n
\log\frac{1}{1-z} 
\; dz
\\ = -\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}}
(z-1)^n  \log\frac{1}{1-z}  \; dz.$$

Now put $$\frac{z}{z-1} = w
\quad\text{so that}\quad
z = -\frac{w}{1-w} 
\\ \text{and}\quad
dz = - \frac{1}{(1-w)^2} dw
\quad\text{and}\quad
\frac{1}{1-z} = 1-w.$$

to get

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}}
(z-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{1-z}  \log\frac{1}{1-z}  \; dz
\\ = - \frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}}
(1-w) \log(1-w) \frac{1}{(1-w)^2} \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{1-w} \log\frac{1}{1-w}  \; dw.$$

This evaluates to $$H_n$$ by inspection since

$$\log\frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{z^q}{q}$$

as seen earlier.

Answer (score 2):

By induction.

Note first that

$$ {n+1 \choose k}={n+1 \choose k}\frac{k}{n+1} +{n \choose k}\tag{1}$$

(lets extend the validity of this equation to the range for $0\le k \le n+1$ by  assuming the convention ${n \choose n+1}=0$)

Also

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} (-1)^{k+1} {n+1 \choose k} =0 \implies \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (-1)^{k+1} {n+1 \choose k}=1 \tag{2}$$

Then assume $\sum_{k=1}^{n}{(-1)^{k+1} {{n}\choose{k}}\frac{1}{k}=H_n}$. Hence

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{k+1} {{n+1}\choose{k}}\frac{1}{k}&=
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{k+1} {{n+1}\choose{k}}\frac{1}{n+1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}{(-1)^{k+1} {{n}\choose{k}}\frac{1}{k}}\\
&=\frac{1}{n+1}+H_n\\
&=H_{n+1}\end{align}$$

To complete the induction, check that $\sum_{k=1}^{1}{(-1)^{k+1} {{1}\choose{k}}\frac{1}{k}}=1=H_1$

(Inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/992751/312), of which this is esentially a particular  case)

Answer (score 2):

The following variation is *Example 3* in section 1.2  of John Riordan's classic *[Combinatorial Identities](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471722758)*.

> Consider for $n=1,2,\ldots$
>   \begin{align*}
> f_n&=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{k}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\left[\binom{n-1}{k}+\binom{n-1}{k-1}\right]\frac{1}{k}\\
> &=f_{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\\
> &=f_{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\left[(1-1)^n-1\right]\\
> &=f_{n-1}+\frac{1}{n}\\
> &=H_n
> \end{align*}
>   since $f_1=1$.