# Hint for proving $H_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\binom{n}{i}\frac{(-1)^{i+1}}i$, where $H_i=\sum_{k=1}^i\frac1k$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, harmonic-numbers

I have been trying to prove the following identity: $$H_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \binom{n}{i}\frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{i}$$ where $$ H_i = \sum_{k=1}^{i} \frac{1}{k} = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots + \frac{1}{i} $$
is the $i$-th harmonic number.

I have been trying to apply various other identites, but to no avail.
What I want to get is but **a hint** on how to solve it, **not the solution**. Please take into consideration the fact that I wish to prove this identity by means of **elementary methods**, i.e. **without calculus, linear algebra or anything college-level**.

I should be exceedingly thankful for any help.

Comment: Why your first fomula is $H_i$, not $H_n$?

Comment: That is a typo, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Maybe proof by induction. Although there is a somewhat clean calculus solution.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha agrees

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving $\sum_{k=1}^{n}{(-1)^{k+1} {{n}\choose{k}}\frac{1}{k}=H_n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842969/proving-sum-k-1n-1k1-n-choosek-frac1k-h-n)

Answer (score 1):

The [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842969/proving-sum-k-1n-1k1-n-choosek-frac1k-h-n) linked by Brian Moehring has a lot of good answers to this (though not hints), but I’d like to add one more that might help provide some insight into why the formula works.

In the diagram below, you can see that $H_5$ is equal to the area of the union of all the rectangles (times some constant). If you use the inclusion exclusion principle to find this area, you can get to the formula your in your question.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

\begin{align*}
H_n&=\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{k}= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_0^1 x^kdx\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{(x-1+1)^n-1}{x-1}dx=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{dx}{1-x}+\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{(x-1)^{k}1^{n-k}}{x-1}dx\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\int_{0}^{1}(x-1)^{k-1}dx =\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\cdot \dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}
\end{align*}